# Which is correct? "I suggest mum (to) invite my auntie"

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct?

> I suggest mum invite my auntie for dinner.

or

> I suggest mum to invite my auntie for dinner.

Is it the same rule on I (recommend)?

Comment: I wouldn't leave out the 'that'. And the covert mandative is far more common here in the UK: "I suggest/recommend that mum invites my auntie for dinner." The periphrastic should construction doesn't sound too natural in these cases; on the other hand, "I suggested that mum invites ..." sounds awful (with the intended meaning), and I'd switch to the mandative subjunctive.

Comment: The question has essentially been asked before: [Tensed verb form or the plain form when used after "that" (in a mandative construction)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145355/tensed-verb-form-or-the-plain-form-when-used-after-that-in-a-mandative-constr). The to-infinitive is not an option. There may be confusion in that "I asked mum to invite my auntie for dinner" certainly takes a to-infinitive.

Comment: "**Suggest** (that) someone..." can be complemented by a clause with the finite verb form (e.g. invites) or with the unmarked infinitive (invite) but not with the marked infinitive (to invite). Same with **recommend**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I suggest Mum to invite...* is not idiomatic.

We usually say *I suggest that [something should happen]*, so *that Mum invites*. You could be saying this to someone else - "It would be a good idea if Mum invited Auntie..."

Or, to emphasise the person who is receiving the suggestion, *I suggest to Mum that she/we should invite Auntie for dinner.* The use of *to* is recommended [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/suggest).

Answer (score 1):

"I suggest mum invites auntie for dinner" might be preferable.

Comment: Or "I suggest to Mum that she/we should/might invite Auntie for dinner".

Comment: Why should the word "to" be included?  It seems superfluous to me.  See comment by TimR.

Comment: See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/suggest).

Comment: Kate, why don't you use this source as the basis for an answer?

Comment: This doesn't sound idiomatic to me, but maybe I'm on the wrong side of the pond.

Comment: @Barmar - There is no right or wrong side of the pond, but the side I'm on prefers to keep things simple.  Perhaps the OP could clarify by providing more information?

Comment: I meant wrong side for that idiom (just as we don't use "mum" much here).

Comment: Lesley: As a heads up, this answer showed up in the "Low quality posts" review queue, maybe because of how short it is.

Comment: @Conrado - appreciate the heads-up, but since Kate's post seems to  answer the question, then I am content to back off.