What is difference between these two constructions?
Here are two constructions:

I suggested that the dish be cooked exactly before the party.

I suggested to cook the dish exactly before the party.


What is the difference between them? Does the first construction mean somebody another, not me, will cook the dish? Does the second construction mean that I will cook dish, not anybody else?

Does 'exactly' refer to how the dish is cooked, or to the timing?

While I'm not sure it's actually wrong, the second sentence does not sound natural. It would be better to use the gerund form instead of the infinitive there: so, "I suggested cooking the dish exactly before the party." (Also, not directly related to your question, but maybe helpful: adverbs like directly or immediately are more idiomatic than 'exactly' when modifying the word "before.")

I propose to cook the meal just before the party.

@WeatherVane Yes, that one works with the infinitive, but I still don't think it's ideal in sentence 2.

Yes, (1) means that you wanted someone else to cook. (2) is not idiomatic. If you are doing the cooking, you could say "I suggested that I should/could cook..." As others have said, exactly is not the right word here.

Then could I write "I suggested that the dish is cooked exactly before the party.", not "I suggested that the dish be cooked exactly before the party."? Are these forms equivalent?

They are not equivalent. For suggesting that someone ought to do something, the subjunctive mood ("be") is the only correct alternative, not the indicative ("is").

The sentence with "is" could be used to mean that you are unsure whether the dish is being cooked or not, but you think that it is; this seems like a fairly unlikely usage though.

Wow, thank you. I merely saw non-typical construction "I suggested that the dish be cooked exactly before the party.", so I was confused a bit. I mean "... be cooked" confused me. I thought it would be right "... is cooked".

If you're looking for information on subjunctive verbs being used in this kind of sentence, here is a discussion you may find helpful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145355/tensed-verb-form-or-the-plain-form-when-used-after-that-in-a-mandative-constr

Does this answer your question? "Suggest to go" vs. "suggest going" (Andrew Leach's answer addresses 'suggest that we go' too.) // Contrary to Quack E. Duck's claim, 'He suggests that the dish is cooked just before the party.' is perfectly acceptable for a suggested course of action, in the UK at least.

As was already said but ignored: 'exactly' isn't the right word. I suggest that the dish be ready just before the party.

What @WeatherVane said. The non-idiomatic use of exactly here strikes me as far more significant (read, noticeable error) than whether to use an infinitive, gerund, or a subjunctive (with or without that) after suggest.

The first example is fine: just a passive subjunctive construction. The second is ungrammatical because the verb "suggest" requires a gerund-participial (ing) clause as its complement, not an infinitival one ("I suggested cooking the dish ...") Btw, I suggest you replace the inappropriate word "exactly" with "just".

Related.
